# Nextjs Ionic error while executing - npx cap sync

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, next.js, capacitor

I am creating a Next.js + Ionic app.
While executing - npx cap sync, I am getting the following error.
[error] The web assets directory (./out) must contain an index.html file.
It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.
How to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you run `next export`? Does the output folder (`out`) from that command not contain an `index.html` file?

Comment: Yes, I ran next export and the output of that doesn't contain any index.html file.